# PyQt5 Function without arguments giving error: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

Tags: pyqt5

I am creating a highly generic template for PyQt5 applications. Without all the comments, here is the code so far. However, executing this code gives the following error:

self.button_widget.clicked.connect(self.functionX)
TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

I am confused about this because the function takes no arguments other than self. What is going on here?

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class mainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.title = 'Window Title'
        self.left = 100
        self.top = 100
        self.width = 750
        self.height = 500
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.do_something()

        self.button_widget = QPushButton()
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_widget, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.widgetX, 1, 0, 1, 3) # row, col, row_span, col_span
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.button_widget.clicked.connect(self.functionX)

    def do_something(self):
        self.widgetX = ClassX()
        self.functionX = self.widgetX.functionX()
        self.variableX = self.widgetX.variableX
    
class ClassX(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassX, self).__init__()

        self.setFixedHeight(40)
        self.setMinimumWidth(600)
        self.setText('I am a Custom QLabel')
        self.variableX = 'X'

    def functionX(self):
        self.setText('I can change text')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = mainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I originally tried using generic arguments like args=None, but this resulted in the same issue. I believe something is going on with using self in both the mainWindow class and the ClassX class. This is NOT the same question as others that ask about this TypeError being given when using a function that takes an argument (like a string or other data type, not self).

Comment: Typo: remove the parentheses from `self.widgetX.functionX()`. When using the parentheses, you're actually calling `functionX()`, which returns `None`, meaning that `self.functionX` then equals to `None`, and you cannot connect to `None` since signal connections need a callable.

Answer (score 2):

```
self.functionX = self.widgetX.functionX()
```

You are calling `functionX` which will give you `None`. To assign function, you just have to remove parenthesis.

```
self.functionX = self.widgetX.functionX
```